# StreamBuilder being called numerous times when in build

Tags: firebase, loops, flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have an application with multiple indexes on a navigation view, when I first load the app, as expected the StreamBuilder is called two times. however, when I navigate to another index and back the build with the stream builder seems to be calling the stream builder to redownload all of the items inside of it. I am worried this is going to consume all of my firebase data if this loop is ran for too long of a period. How could I restructure to stop the StreamBuilder from being called many times when switching pages. Note, I even save the state of this index when I switch and come back.

My build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection("posts/player/post")
            .orderBy("time", descending: true)
            .snapshots()
            .take(2),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          final int highLightCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
          return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection("posts/player/post")
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData)
                  return new Text("There are no current posts");
                return new ListView(
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: getPostItems(snapshot),
                );
              });
        });
  }
```

When I switch it is calling the getPostItem(snaphot) that is being called nearly nonstop, how could I prevent this from being called and consuming my data, or, prevent the StreamBuilder from changing unless something actually updates?

The rest of the important code:

```
getPostItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) => getListItem(doc)).toList();
  }

  Widget getListItem(var doc) {
    getProfUrl(doc);
    getDownUrl(doc);

    print("item hit");

    print("user: " + doc["user"] + "- current: " + widget.auth.getUserId());
    if (doc["user"] != widget.auth.getUserId()) {
      print("will show");
      if (doc["type"] == "image") {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
                title: new Text(doc["title"]),
                subtitle: new Text(doc["description"].toString()),
                leading: new Container(
                    width: 44.0,
                    height: 44.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(profUrl)),
                    ))),
            new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
              child: new Center(
                child: new AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                  child: new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                      image: new NetworkImage(downUrl),
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      } else {
        VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
            'http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
          ..initialize().then((_) {
            // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
            setState(() {});
          });

        return new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
              title: new Text(doc["title"]),
              subtitle: new Text(doc["description"].toString()),
              leading: new Container(
                  width: 44.0,
                  height: 44.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(profUrl)),
                  ))),
          new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
            child: new Center(
              child: new AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 500 / 500,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to reduce the number of times that the `Stream` is being created, you could move its initialisation into the `initState` method of the `State` class.

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _outerStream;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _innerStream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _outerStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
        final int highLightCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _innerStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('There are no current posts');
            return ListView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: getPostItems(snapshot),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _outerStream = Firestore
        .instance
        .collection('posts/player/post')
        .orderBy('time', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .take(2);

    _innerStream = Firestore
        .instance
        .collection('posts/player/post')
        .snapshots();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to create the `Stream` once during the lifetime of the application, then you could use a `StreamProvider` to provide the `Stream`.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>(
          create: (context) {
            return Firestore.instance.collection('posts/player/post').snapshots();
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final snapshot = context.watch<QuerySnapshot>();

    return Scaffold(
      body: snapshot == null
          ? Text('There are no current posts')
          : ListView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: getPostItems(snapshot),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This was an awesome response! I've been struggling a lot with this when using FutureBuilder's and StreamBuilders, the example code was awesome too!

Comment: If you have a moment, could you share with me why you have the inner and the outer stream? It appears as if one checks if they exist and the second displays, is that correct?

Comment: Glad the code samples were useful, happy to help! I noticed in your code sample that you had two different streams. I simply named the properties outer and inner to highlight them, so feel free to rename them to something more meaningful. You are correct, the outer stream is used in the `Text('Loading...')` and the `final int highLightCount`, whilst the inner stream is used in the `Text('There are no current posts')` and the `ListView(...)`.

Comment: Peeerfeeeeeccctttt!!!!!!!!..... I was stuck here for dayyyss!... This code helped a loooott!!